# Bash subshell in Terminal has Mac OS's session save enabled

Tags: terminal, bash

At some point, Terminal started saving sessions. It's controlled with `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`. For some reason, my subshells are also using this feature:

```
echo $(cd && pwd)
/Users/ehrmann Saving session... ...saving history...truncating history files... ...completed.
```

As a workaround, I can do

```
echo $(SHELL_SESSION_FILE= && cd && pwd)
```

Luckily, it works across platforms, but it's kinda silly.

Did I accidentally do something that turned this on? This can't be the intended default behavior—it breaks all sorts of things.

Comment: This is NOT the default behaviour. Something else is causing it. In my case it was caused by rvm (Ruby version manager) redefining cd; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561851/how-does-rvm-gets-invoked-while-going-into-a-folder-with-gemfile

Answer (score 4):

I’m not certain when this became the default, but I agree, it’s an annoying default; it was added in one of the last few major releases. I came across this question because I was searching for how to best disable this, and I think you may have provided the solution yourself:

In `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`, there is great amount of documentation about how the functionality in the file is implemented.

The final comment is the kicker:

```
# The save/restore mechanism is disabled if the following file exists:
#
#   ~/.bash_sessions_disable
```

I tested this on my machine and it works, no more session saving.

Comment: This disables *all* session save/restore in Apple Terminal.app. OP is referring to subshells.